# override uniqueIdentifier method of ios

Tags: iphone, ios, udid

I need to send a different udid to my database for few testing purpose. Since [UIDevice currentDevice] uniqueIdentifier] is called in almost 15 places it will be very difficult for me to make a code change and then test. Is there a way to override that method for a while and send a another number as udid ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to override it in a category on UIDevice. Create a header like this:

```
@interface UIDevice (overrideId)

@property (nonatomic,readonly,retain) NSString *uniqueIdentifier

@end
```

And then a .m like this:

```
@implementation UIDevice (overrideId)

- (NSString *)uniqueIdentifier {
    return @"whatever";
}

@end
```

Don't forget to remove it again before releasing.

Answer (score 2):

You could create a category on UIDevice and override uniqueIdentifier to return a random value.

```
@interface UIDevice (RandomIdentifier)

@property (nonatomic, retain, readonly) NSString *uniqueIdentifier

@end

@implementation UIDevice (RandomIdentifier)

- (NSString *)uniqueIdentifier
{
    return @"Randomly generated string";
}

@end
```